# Is it safe to have a wall wart plugged in to a receptacle in an attic?

Tags: electrical, safety, attic

I'm trying to move my router to get better reception through my house. There is a perfect spot just below the ceiling in the middle of my house.

I can run the CAT5 no problem, however, I'm worried about connecting the "wall wart" of the router to an outlet inside the attic.

Is it safe to keep an AC-DC plug in the attic?  What would be the safest way to get power to this router (hopefully not piggy-backing off the attic outlet 5' and cutting a hole in the ceilings for a  recessed outlet haha )?

Comment: Is there an outlet already where you want to place the router? Do you know of the router can take the temperatures which are common in attics?

Comment: The router would be inside the house pointing downward and there is an outlet in the attic already on a cross beam.   So I was going to run the DC cable and the CAT through the ceiling into the attic.  I'm just worried about the wart catching fire or some other electrical hazard.

Answer (score 1):

Use POE (Power over Ethernet), check to see if the router supports it directly, otherwise get a power injector and pickup (Cisco Linksys for example, has them available to power their wireless/router or WAP products).

This was the easiest to use a wireless bridge between two buildings where the antenna would be located 50' from the computers that needed the link and the inside Ethernet switch respectively.

This keeps the 120VAC wallwart out of the attic and exposure to excess heat and converts the power transmission requirements to low voltage over the CAT-X Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem; modern wall-cube supplies from reputable manufacturers have built-in protection against overtemperature, overload, and other such faults.  Of course, PoE is also an option.

Comment: Any concerns with the router being in the living space, while the power supply is in the attic?